# Mongo Find multiple matching inside and array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

What I am doing is having a list of all documents entered by the client on the page.  Then I have multiple search boxes that they can use to narrow down the documents.  Each search box is tied to a field.  I want to be able to search and narrow down the results as they are typing.  One of the fields that I need to search into as an array that hold other objects. I can successful accomplish this if the field(s) they are searching against are in the base of the object but I fail to find a way to search into the array of objects.  An example of the complete object is below.

```
{
"_id" : "fNgY9TcdCnyEFwePT",
"companyCode" : "demoAccount1",
"tripNumber" : 5002,
"tripNumberText" : "5002",
"custID" : "TnfFBRt3bZvNrSRB7",
"customerName" : "Am Transport Inc",
"orderLoadNum" : "50021321",
"orderPlacedDate" : ISODate("2016-01-27T08:00:00.000Z"),
"orderDispatch" : [ 
    {
        "Address" : "4111 Aurora Ave N",
        "Appt" : "",
        "Cases" : "",
        "City" : "Seattle",
        "Contact" : "",
        "Customer" : "ABC 1",
        "DatePuDel" : ISODate("2016-01-27T08:00:00.000Z"),
        "Email" : "",
        "Fax" : "",
        "Notes" : "",
        "ParsPaps" : "",
        "Phone1" : "",
        "Phone2" : "",
        "Ref" : "",
        "Skids" : "",
        "State" : "WA",
        "Suite" : "",
        "Weight" : "",
        "Zip" : "98103",
        "carrierCharges" : "",
        "carrierCurrency" : "CDN",
        "carrierName" : "",
        "driverName" : "",
        "stop" : true,
        "stopDelDate" : "",
        "stopDelTime" : "",
        "stopNum" : 0,
        "stopPuDate" : "",
        "stopPuTime" : "",
        "stopType" : "pickup",
        "trailerNum" : "",
        "truckNum" : "",
        "deliveryType" : "",
        "deliveryStatus" : "Entered"
    }, 
    {
        "Address" : "8325 Main St",
        "Appt" : "",
        "Cases" : "",
        "City" : "Vancouver",
        "Contact" : "",
        "Customer" : "ABC 2",
        "DatePuDel" : ISODate("2016-01-27T08:00:00.000Z"),
        "Email" : "",
        "Fax" : null,
        "Notes" : "",
        "ParsPaps" : "",
        "Phone1" : "",
        "Phone2" : "",
        "Ref" : "",
        "Skids" : "",
        "State" : "WA",
        "Suite" : "",
        "Weight" : "",
        "Zip" : "V5X 3M3",
        "carrierCharges" : "",
        "carrierCurrency" : "CDN",
        "carrierName" : "",
        "driverName" : "Test Driver 1",
        "stop" : false,
        "stopDelDate" : "",
        "stopDelTime" : "",
        "stopNum" : 1,
        "stopPuDate" : "",
        "stopPuTime" : "",
        "stopType" : "delivery",
        "trailerNum" : 4412,
        "truckNum" : 101,
        "stopMiles" : "182.2",
        "deliveryType" : "Highway",
        "deliveryStatus" : "Dispatched",
        "truckNumText" : "101",
        "trailerNumText" : "4412"
    }
  ]
}
```

So what I have tested is below.  I am just trying to isolate a way to search multiple fields inside the orderDispatch right now then I will add back in other fields.

```
        query = {"$and": [
            { "$elemMatch" :{"orderDispatch.trailerNumText": {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=traceBoardTrailerNumSetting]').val(), 'i')}}},
            { "$elemMatch" :{"orderDispatch.carrierName":    {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=traceBoardCarrierSetting]').val(), 'i')}}},
            { "$elemMatch" :{"orderDispatch.truckNumText":   {$regex: new RegExp('^' + $('input:text[name=traceBoardTruckSetting]').val(), 'i')}}}
        ]};
```

I have tried multiple things and none seem to work.  A point int he right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why `$and` instead of `$or` when searching multiple fields? Unlikely they would all contain the same pattern at the same time no?

Comment: That is the point. This would allow the use to greatly narrow his search by being able have multiple fields checked against. If I use or then the returned data will not be as zoned in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error in your query :

Use following syntax for `$elemMatch` query :

```
db.collectionName.find(
    {"$and": [
            { "orderDispatch" : { "$elemMatch" :{ "trailerNumText": {$regex: new RegExp('^' + 'insert your value here', 'i')}}} },
            { "orderDispatch" : { "$elemMatch" :{ "carrierName":    {$regex: new RegExp('^' + 'insert your value here', 'i')}}} },
            { "orderDispatch" : { "$elemMatch" :{ "truckNumText":   {$regex: new RegExp('^' + 'insert your value here', 'i')}}} }
        ]}
)
```